# Remove unique values in textfile - if else - Python

Tags: if-statement, python-3.x, for-loop, text

I have a text file looking like the following:

```
A   B   C   D
0   4   3   5
3   3   5   8
8   1   5   7
9   3   7   9
```

The data is sorted by column C.
What I am trying to do, is to write a Python (3.4) that deletes each line, where the value in column C does not equal the value of column C in another line.
So I need to pull out all lines, that have one or more matching values of column C.
The mockup code below, is my attempt to show what I want to do:

```
For loop
    if lineXcolumnY == lineX2columnY2
    OR
    if lineX2columnY2 == lineXcolumnY
        print line X
    Else
        Delete line X
```

On the above example of data, the code would then give me:

```
A   B   C   D
3   3   5   8
8   1   5   7
```

I am a complete newbie to Python, so what is confusing me a lot, is how to actually refer to the text file in the script, and how to refer to a specific column. In R I would do Data$C to refer to the column, but in Python?

Comment: Is the C column like `[3,  5, 5, 7, 1 ]` or can it be like `[3, 5, 5, 7, 7, 1]`; that is, does it contain a single repeated element?

Comment: It contains several (many) repeated elements, and they may be repeated more than once. So like this `3, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 10, 10, 13, 14, 15, 15`
So here I would like an ouput **without** the lines containing C = 3, 7, 8, 13, 14.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`collections.deque`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) with max length 2 , to keep 2 lines in each iteration then compare their 3th columns :

```
from collections import deque
q = deque(maxlen=2)
last_q=deque()
with open('newefile.txt','r') as f:

   for line in f:
        q.append(line.strip())
        if len(q)==2 :
            if q[0].split()[2]==q[1].split()[2] :
                last_q.extend(q)
                print q[0],'\n',q[1]
```

and at last you can write the result on `last_q` in your file :

```
with open('newefile.txt','w') as f:
     for line in last_q :
          f.write(line)
```

result :

```
3   3   5   8 
8   1   5   7
```

In this code you need to append the lines to your `deque` in every iteration :

```
q.append(line.strip())
```

So then you need to check the length of `q` with :

```
if len(q)==2
```

Then you can access the 3rd column with splitting the lines and then pick the 3rd element :

```
q[0].split()[2]
```

And if there was equal you can put the `deque` to `last_q` , with `extend` :

```
if q[0].split()[2]==q[1].split()[2] : 
      last_q.extend(q)
```

Comment: Thank you, @Kasra AD. As I am a newbie, this method is a bit more complicated for me to understand, than the if else method, although I am sure it is smarter.
Can you explain a bit more of the logic to me?
Where in the code do you define, that you want to search in column 3?
Is that `if len(q)==2 :`

I have read in a csv file instead of txt file, and I have each line as a list.
However, when I run your code, I get the error `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Program_test2.py", line 16, in <module>
    if q[0].split()[2]==q[1].split()[2] :
IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Regarding the .csv problem: It's working with .txt, so I must have some problem with the .csv input.